# Raster Calculation Using GDAL

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I want to perform raster calculation from GDAL tool. I am using the formula as,

```
 gdal_calc.py -A Input_File.tif --outfile=yourOutput.tif -- calc="(A>=2200)*A" --NoDataValue=0 --type='Float32'
```

But the above statement gives an Error

> ImportError : numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.

Comment: `-- calc="(A>=2200)*A"` should be `--calc="(A>=2200)*A"` (without space)

Comment: did this too. but same error

Comment: try to update numpy: `pip install -U numpy`